# Python - NameError: name 'engine' is not defined / Driver not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyttsx

I have been trying to work on an AI Project in PyCharm using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=179&v=rU_ppVsyJu8

Here is the code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except ImportError:
    print("Driver not found")
except RuntimeError:
    print("Driver fails to init")

voices = engine.getProperty("voices")

for voice in voices:
    print(voice.id)
```

And there is an error:

[image]

Even though it says driver not found, I installed pyttsx3 right here:

[image]

I have been tackling this problem for a week, and with it I can't move on. If someone helped that would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you activated the virtualenv?

Comment: What is the actual error message? Try running `import pyttsx3` and then `engine = pyttsx3.init()` from a Python prompt - you may be missing another module that `pyttsx3` depends on. It looks like the `import pyttsx3` line in your program worked.

Comment: @subnivean I tried that and here is the error: https://pastebin.com/hjm1MFLy

Comment: @C.Nivs How do I do that, sorry it is my first time using PyCharm

Comment: @C.Nivs idk I think I may have already activated it

Comment: Based on the full error message, you might read up at https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/28; the short of it is to try `pip install pyobjc`. I'm on Linux, not a Mac, so I can't test.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to execute `engine = pyttsx3.init()`. That's why it's not recognizing the engine object. Try the code below. You will get the error message from Exception. Try to solve that error.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
**except Exception as e:
    print(e)**
except ImportError:
    print("Driver not found")
except RuntimeError:
    print("Driver fails to init")

voices = engine.getProperty("voices")

for voice in voices:
    print(voice.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to fix. I also use Pycharm and other code editors.
Just open YOUR Project and if your code is still the same just do this:

Put this line: `engine = pyttsx3.init()` after `import pyttsx3` or just remove your full code and copy/paste this code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
except ImportError:
    print("Driver not found")
except RuntimeError:
    print("Driver fails to init")

voices = engine.getProperty("voices")

for voice in voices:
    print(voice.id)
```

I always get's these kind of errors. OK, it's the fix for this problem now. I am going to fix the error:

> NameError: name 'audio' is not defined

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and easy solution for this pyaudio error:

**Step 1:** Visit this link
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

**Step 2:** Search your python version example, I have python 3.9.6 win32(amd64)
then I selected and downloaded cp39 win32(amd64) and installed it using simple click.

**Step 3:** Go on that downloaded folder where your file has downloaded and then open there Powershell and then type

```
pip install .\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

Now by following these steps, I think your error will be resolved.